# squid3 PAM_Auth authentication not working

Tags: 11.10, networking, server, squid

I'm attempting to run a squid3 proxy server with authentication for any user that has a login to the server.

I've followed [these](http://abechik.wordpress.com/2008/12/26/ubuntu-810-squid3-with-pam_auth-revisited/) instructions, and I am prompted for a username and password when I enter the proxy details. Problem is it won't accept my root username and password or another account that I have. I am sure I'm entering the password correctly. I checked the log and I see :

> 1359436167.010   1281 174.XX.XX.XX TCP_DENIED/407 5219 GET http://abechik.wordpress.com/2008/12/26/ubuntu-810-squid3-with-pam_auth-revisited/ root NONE/- text/html

Any ideas?

EDIT: Config file here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1603430/
I pretty much followed the instructions on [this](http://abechik.wordpress.com/2008/12/26/ubuntu-810-squid3-with-pam_auth-revisited/) blog.

Also just to ensure I understand this right: I have a local user 'BOMEz' with password 'password'. I can log into the system via putty over SSH. When Firefox I am prompted for the password I enter BOMEz and password and it just asks for the password again. I'd like to be able to just make Linux user accounts which will automatically have proxy access.

Comment: Please post your cache.log and squid.conf. Upload them to http://paste.ubuntu.com and post the links here.

Comment: Added paste of config file.

Comment: cache.log would be helpful. Try this: run `/usr/lib/squid3/pam_auth`, it should wait for input, type `username password` (real/valid username and password). It should output `OK` or `ERR`, maybe with an error message.

Comment: Here is cache.log http://paste.ubuntu.com/1614976/ Also added some extra details to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. This solved it:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/squid3/pam_auth
```

It seems pam_auth needs special permissions for other users. `squid3` ran with the user "proxy". I switched to this user with `su -u squid` and tested `/usr/lib/squid3/pam_auth`. It returns OK if given username and password separated with a space when executed as the same user or root.